# How can I retrieve all the child pages in Confluence by a parent page title?

Tags: python, rest, confluence

I know how to retrieve a page in Confluence by its title

```
res = requests.get(BASE_URL + "/confluence/rest/api/content", params={"title": "parent page title"} , auth=("username", "pass"))
```

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/confluence-rest-api-examples

How can I retrieve all the child pages given a parent page title?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I see it, you can't search child pages by their parent's **title**. You need to search with the parent's **Id**.

Try the following to get the parent id:

```
/rest/api/content/search?cql=title=<parentTitle>
```

If you only have the parent's title, you need to send a second call first to get the id from the title

```
/rest/api/content/search?cql=parent=<parentId>
```

Id and children cannot be found with */confluence/rest/api/content*, so this is not going to work:

```
res = requests.get(BASE_URL + "/confluence/rest/api/content", params={"parent": "<parentId>"} , auth=("username", "pass"))

res = requests.get(BASE_URL + "/confluence/rest/api/content", params={"title": "parents title"} , auth=("username", "pass"))
```

Comment: for some reason it still returns all the pages, the parent pages of the parent page too.

Comment: You are right, my suggestion only works for "/search", which leads to /rest/api/content/search?cql=parent=<parentId>. please try this.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297769/retrieve-all-the-child-pages-in-confluence-the-1st-solution-doesnt-work-proper ?

Comment: I saw this question. I'm not sure what you want to achieve - only searching or manipulationg content? For searching just use the /rest/api/content/search?cql=parent=<parentId> url, which is powerful and documented.

Comment: are you absolutely sure that `/rest/api/content/search?cql=parent=<parentId>` returns only the child pages of the parent page? What I want to achieve is written in my question.

Comment: just test it with a page and only 1 child page. you can paste the search string to your browser and see the results (you have to be logged in first).

Comment: the question was "are you absolutely sure..."?

Comment: whaaayy, you're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a complete solution that uses recursion and does it off space key. Even though the original question was asking about how to do it off of only the title, I thought I'd show how it would all work in a single, compact script.

This script will iterate through an entire space, given its space key, and then print out the title of every page and child page.

```py
import json
import requests
import builtins


class list(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(args)

    def print(self):
        for i in self:
            print(f"{i}")

    def append_unique(self, item):
        if item not in self:
            self.append(item)


class Requests:
    def __init__(self, requests_username, requests_secret_file_name, requests_url_root):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.auth = (requests_username, self.load_password(requests_secret_file_name))
        self.url_root = requests_url_root

    @staticmethod
    def load_password(file_name):
        with open(f"{file_name}") as f: contents = f.read()
        return contents

    def get_top_level_space_content(self, space_key):
        url = f"{self.url_root}/rest/api/content?spaceKey={space_key}"
        response = self.session.get(url)
        return str(response.text)


class Parser:
    def __init__(self, parser_requests):
        self.page_names = list()
        self.page_ids = list()
        self.parser_requests = parser_requests

    def extract_list_of_page_ids(self, content):
        as_json = json.loads(content)
        content_list = dict(as_json).get('results')
        if content_list is None:
            return
        for c_l in content_list:
            if c_l.get('type') == 'page':
                self.page_titles.append_unique(c_l.get("title"))
                self.page_ids.append_unique(c_l.get("id"))
                self.extract_list_of_page_ids(
                    self.parser_requests.session.get(f'{requests.url_root}/rest/api/content/search?cql=parent='
                                                     f'{c_l.get("id")}').text)
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # I wrote this with a .gitignore that ignores *.secret files
    # I recommend using an access token and not a password
    username, secret_file_name, url_root = "username", \
                                           "file_containing_password.secret", \
                                           "https://confluence-wiki-root.com"

    requests = Requests(username, secret_file_name, url_root)

    parser = Parser(requests)

    space_content = parser.parser_requests.get_top_level_space_content("SPACE-KEY")

    parser.extract_list_of_page_ids(space_content)

    parser.page_names.print()
```

- **NOTE 1: Works with on-prem Confluence 7.7.4**
- **NOTE 2: I will be the first to admit, it's not the fastest thing I've ever written, but it was a first pass. Maybe I can optimize later.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a 1-line code to answer your question

```
confluence.get_space_content(space_key, depth="all", start=0, limit=100, content_type='page', expand="body.storage")
```

Note that there is limit of 100 pages to cull per time, so you will have to construct a loop.

See ths link [https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html#:~:text=confluence.get_space_content(space_key%2C%20depth%3D%22all%22%2C%20start%3D0%2C%20limit%3D500%2C%20content_type%3DNone%2C%20expand%3D%22body.storage%22)](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html#:%7E:text=confluence.get_space_content(space_key%2C%20depth%3D%22all%22%2C%20start%3D0%2C%20limit%3D500%2C%20content_type%3DNone%2C%20expand%3D%22body.storage%22)) for refeence